# Keep GoLang Server Running

Tags: terminal

I run the server.go file using "iTerm2" software from my macbook pro. But as the server's availability depends upon that "iTerm2" running or not it stops working as soon as my macbook pro goes in sleep mode or the iTerm2 software is interrupted in any way. I need my GoLang Server to run 24x7. What do I do? I tried searching on google and since my English is not good I can not find the right answer.

I have been trying to find a solution for this problem from weeks now.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tmux` or `screen` put the session run in the background.

Or just `run your command &; disown`

Otherwise, your computer shutting down or getting into sleep will both interrupt or pause the background process, so in real world 24x7, you need a cloud service unless keeping your computer running 24x7.